# Change Title Spacing

Tags: spacing, titlesec

I am currently trying to fulfill the layout requirements of my university, which request vertical spacing of 24pt before and 12pt after section titles. I am using the `titlesec` package, but every time I try to set the document, I only get problems. In my document, I am using `\section, \subsection, \section* and \subsection*`, yet it doesn't work. My preamble`s code looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,draft]{article}

\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} % Eingabekodierung: UTF-8
\usepackage{fixltx2e} % Schickere Ausgabe
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % ordentliche Trennung
\usepackage[french,USenglish,UKenglish,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern} % ordentliche Schriften
\usepackage[babel,style=swiss]{csquotes}
\usepackage{extsizes}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=3.5cm,left=2.5cm,right=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lettrine}

\usepackage{titlesec}
    \titlespacing*{\section}{}{24pt}{12pt}
    \titlespacing{\section*}{}{24pt}{12pt}
    \titlespacing*{\subsection}{}{24pt}{12pt}
    \titlespacing*{\subsection*}{}{24pt}{12pt}

\usepackage[]{acronym}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{\rightmark}
\lhead{} 
\rfoot{\thepage}

% \pagenumbering{arabic}
```

Comment: If you need different spacings for numbered and unnumbered sections, `titlesec` provides the `numberless` key. Also, beware  the `*`  after `\titlespacing` is there to kill indentation of the first section paragraph.

Comment: Also n needless to load `fixltx2e` unless you have an old distribution.

Comment: Actually I am also wondering, why it is still there, I wanted to implement some lines from a nice template I found from our Institute for Informatics, but erased them later, yet, still they load `fixltx2e`. Do you have any idea, how to stop that?

Comment: I don't  quite follow you. You erased theses lines from a template on your own computer, and finally they're still there?

Comment: Yes, and I also deleted the log files and so on, yet this warning still shows up.

Comment: You mean the `Package fixltx2e Warning: fixltx2e is not required with releases after 2015(fixltx2e) All fixes are now in the LaTeX kernel.`? It should disappear after removing the `\usepackage{fixltx2e}` and recompiling.

Comment: Maybe redo the formats.

Comment: I found what's wrong and deleted everything. Now this warning doesn't appear anylonger. Maybe you could help me with another question I posed? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314213/header-problems?noredirect=1#comment766281_314213

Answer (score 3):

`titlespacing` does not allow the starred `\section*` commands as arguments. Instead, a `\section*` gets the same spacing that you set for a normal, numbered `\section`. Simply replace your four `\titlespacing` commands with the two from the code below.

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{24pt}{12pt}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{24pt}{12pt}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\section*{Testsection}
\blindtext
\section{Testsection}
\blindtext
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: I did it, I guess it cannot show, because my reputation is not high enough, yet. :(